# greatest term in multinomial expansion proof

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

Can anyone give the proof for greatest term in multinomial expansion (coefficients of x are not 1)and an intuitive sense for the formula.Our book just contains the formula without any understanding of it.

Comment: "The greatest term in multinomial expansion"?  Are you asking about the greatest term in  the multinomial expansion $(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k)^n$ where the coefficients of each inside are $1$?  Or are you asking for the greatest term in the multinomial expansion $(\alpha_1 x_1+\alpha_2 x_2+\dots+\alpha_k x_k)^n$ where the coefficients might be different than $1$?  For instance, $(x+y)^2 = x^2\color{red}{+2xy}+y^2$ and the middle term is largest but $(x+3y)^2 = x^2+6xy\color{red}{+9y^2}$ and the third term is largest

Comment: @JMoravitz , different than 1( the second type)

Comment: As it is more general, I guess it will be more useful to know that one